# Minimum Hardware requirements for Android development

Tags: android

Need information about minimum hardware requirement for better experience in developing Android application.

My current configuration is as follows. P4 3.0 GHz, 512 MB of ram.

Started with Hello Android development on my machine and experience was sluggish, was using Eclipse Helios for development. Emulator used to take lot of time to start. And running program too.
Do I need to upgrade my machine for the development purpose or is there anything else I am missing on my machine(like heavy processing by some other application I might have installed).

And If I do need to upgrade, do I need to upgrade my processor too(that counts to new machine actually, which I am not in favor of), or only upgrading RAM will suffice.

Comment: The biggest difference maker I found is ensuring HAXM is properly installed.  Just selecting it from the SDK Manager is not enough.  Intel only, but you have a P4.  http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#acceleration

Comment: Since this question keep receiving upvotes I am assuming people are not able to find the documentation which is available now, so here is the link for you https://developer.android.com/studio#system-requirements-a-namerequirementsa

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Firstly, there is an issue with the ADT plugin and Helios which causes lag with looking up Android classes - use Galileo instead (v3.5).

Secondly, the emulators become more resource hungry depending on the version of Android you're developing for. Example, I have a P4 2.4GHz, 1GB RAM PC with Win XP 32-bit and an Android v2.2 emulator takes at least 4-5 minutes to load up. An Android v1.6 emulator on the other hand loads up in less than 1 minute. Remember though that once the emulator is up and running, you can leave it loaded and it will be more responsive than first use.

Also bear in mind that if you give your emulator a 2GB SD card (for example) it will try to create that through virtual memory if there isn't enough physical memory.

Comment: good redirection, I was using 2.2 emulator. Will try others as well. And will take care of not configuring any extra memory for emulator.. And galileo is first work to do for me now...

Comment: Increasing the RAM will help a lot. 512 MB is not good for any kind of Java development using Eclipse. Android emulator even asks for more. Just moving to 1 GB of RAM will do wonders. 2 GB of RAM should be better.

Comment: i would suggest developing on a real device like google nexus one. my emulator performance is also very low even though i am using galileo, i have 2 gb ram, 2.6 ghz dualcore.

Comment: Tried Galieleo, response was better of this eclipse version, than that of Helios. But no major improvement in Android, tried 1.6 platform too, But no help. I guess I will go with adding RAM.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion , Jaywalker and Markus Drösser. @Jaywalker: Thing was that, I never used my home machine with eclipse for any kind of development(*never needed to do that, learned whole of core java with notepad,  thought of even doing the same thing with Android, if there's way.*). So you are right in saying that, its not fit for any development using eclipse. It used to lag when using eclipse. Was just confirming the thing before going for up-gradation. Next stop 2 GB RAM :D

Answer (score 15):

I did the following experiment at home:

let's compare how 2 computers compile the same android application in eclipse. Here are the competitors:

"the monster"
- pentinum i7 
- 16 gig RAM 
- solid state hard drive

"peabody"
- pentinum i3
- 4 gig RAM

The results:
when I compiled the same application in eclipse, the monster and peabody took exactly the same amount of time to bring up the emulator to the point where you have to slide the button to run the app: 1 minute 12 seconds.

After that point, the monster executed the app 30-40 seconds faster than peabody.

The monster costs about $500 more than the peabody. So the question is, is it really worth it? In my opinion, No. I can wait the extra 30-40 seconds

Comment: The point is..... maybe you have no enough RAM to open more than a few tabs in Chrome with 4GB :)

Answer (score 7):

I use an i5 processor with 4Gb RAM. It works very well. I feel this is the minimum configuration required to run both eclipse and android avd simultaneously.
Just an old processor with high RAM is not sufficient.

Comment: an SSD could help it though

Comment: I am new to android development,I am using i5 processor and 4GB Ram,system gets stuck when open both android studio and avd..could you help me to resolve..?

Comment: Try reducing the size of the RAM in AVD

Answer (score 2):

IMHO it is cpu and RAM dependant. On my Wolfdale (with Intel virtualisation technology) + 4GB of RAM it's very fast and usable. As I know the emu is qemu based so it`s better to have Intel with virtualisation tech enabled and don't forget to insert any virulatisation modules to the kernel (if using linux).

Comment: update for 2017. Is that spec still relevant for today?

Comment: Yes, tried on a Intel dual core @3GHz with Intel Virtualization Technology and Geforce 8600GT, 6GB RAM, Windows 10 x64 and even the latest Andndroid Studio - 3 - works at an acceptable speed. Apparently a quad core at a lower speed (Q6600 @ 2.4GHz the rest of the spec is similar) is worse - nearly unusable.  Using Noxplayer and Genymotion however for better emulation speed. BTW. On AMD (even Ryzen) emulation worked for me only in Linux!

Answer (score 1):

Its of no use even if you increase your RAM size because I tried it too. I am using P4 3.00GHz processor and 3 GB RAM(changed from 1 GB to 3GB), But even the Hello world application never turned up.

Its preferable to upgrade your system.

Comment: Though this question is old, this information will surely help somebody else...

Answer (score 1):

I've just started using Java on Eclipse (Juno) after a 15 year break from Java.  I was using the ADK on a 1.6GHz Atom N270 with 4Gb RAM on W7 32bit on a nearly empty disk.  Not sure if it is the Atom or whether Java is as bad as it used to be 15 years ago but it takes over 2 minutes for Eclipse to even start.  The emulator does turn up eventually but is extremely sluggish.  Even without the emulator, Eclipse is sluggish.

On a 1.6GHz Core i7 or a 2GHz Core 2 Duo, operation is reasonable.  Emulator works, Eclipse takes about 5 to 10 seconds to be ready for work.  Moral of the story: don't use an Atom or any other low powered processor.  It is sluggish even with 4Gb memory and having the same clock speed as a high end processor.

I've also tried it in a VMWare VM on the 1.6GHz Core i7 and on the Core 2.  It is reasonably fast until the the emulator is started.   It then slows down to the point of no return.  Redraws is now very much like that of the Atom but at least it responds when the buttons are clicked.  Note that it is now running an emulator within an emulator.  The only problem with VMs is that every so often W7 does what W7 does.  There is a wait cursor and whole machine is totally unresponsive for a minute or two then it springs back to life.  This was with VMWare V3.  V4/V5 might be different.  Varying the number of cores/processors did not make any difference to eclipse or the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

I use **DUAL CORE 3-GHZ** with **2GB RAM**, **windows 8 OS**.

I can run eclipse and AVD (**even running 2 AVD is still good**) smoothly, as long as i dont open too much other tabs (Game, Browser, MS Word, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the android SDK system requirements [Here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html)

I'm guessing some extra RAM would help your developing experience...Also the emulator does take some time to start on even the speediest systems.

Comment: already had, it talks about Operating systems and dependent libraries. But not about hardware requirement, though there is para with heading *Hardware requirements*, it only has information file download size...

Comment: looks like, adding ram should do...

Answer (score 0):

Hey, I have used the same software on an AMD 3Ghz chip, dual core. had 2gbs of ram at the time, and i noticed the emulator ran at an alright speed, but took a ridiculous amount of time to load. 
I have not done enough development on Android to tell you if this is a common, or even still existing problem, but it is certainly something I remember from my experience.

Comment: Heard that loading is boot-up process and will take time, that's not worry if its a common problem... if after loading for first time, it was running fine, then I need to have a look at my hardware.. cause your mentioned hardware is double or triple of what I have ....

Answer (score 0):

I find identically-specced AVDs run and load far better on my home machine (Phenom II x4 945/8GB RAM/Win7 HP 64bit) than they do on my work machine (Core2Duo/3GB RAM/Ubuntu 11.04 32bit).

As you're essentially running a virtual machine, I would personally go for nothing less than a `dual core/4GB`, though highly recommend a quad/8GB if you can splash out for that.