# What are the minimum hardware requirements for the latest ADT Bundle?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I use `Eclipse Indigo` with `ADT` plugin and `Android SDK`. 
It used to work fine in my `Athlon X2 64` with `2 GB RAM` at my office.

Recently I downloaded the newly released `ADT` bundle. Its hassle free to install and can start development straight away. But the `IDE` and `Emulator` seems to eat up my `RAM` and takes ages to load.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Check this site: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html; I'm afraid your hardware might not be sufficient

Comment: Probably this thread will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533116/minimum-hardware-requirements-for-android-development